# umbraco datatypes and text value from code behind

Tags: umbraco

I am trying to get the text value of a dropdown list from the API and I am seriously struggling.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Document doc = new Document(Node.GetCurrent().Id);

doc.GetProperty("fieldPropertyName").Value;
```

This returns a string representation of the id for the prevalue.

What I want is the text for that pre value.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have found a way to do this by looping over the pre-values, but it feels somewhat klunky. Does nobody have a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please excuse this being in VB.

This is the language I happened to be developing in. (How I wish I could use C#)

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web
Imports umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype

Module UmbracoExtensionHelper


    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetCustomPropertyValueFromPreValues(ByVal doc As Document, ByVal propertyName As String)
        Dim returnValue As String = ""
        Dim objProperty As umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property = doc.getProperty(propertyName)

        If objProperty IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim objPreValues = PreValues.GetPreValues(objProperty.PropertyType.DataTypeDefinition.Id)
            If objPreValues IsNot Nothing Then

                ''run through the ids of the datatypes and the value of the property
                For Each entry As DictionaryEntry In objPreValues
                    Dim currentPreValue As PreValue = CType(entry.Value, PreValue)
                    If currentPreValue.Id.ToString().ToLower() = objProperty.Value.ToString().ToLower() Then
                        returnValue = currentPreValue.Value.ToLower()
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            End If
        End If

        Return returnValue
    End Function




End Module
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the library function...

```
var stringValue = umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(Convert.ToInt32(doc.GetProperty("fieldName").Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code

aspx page

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="selectbox" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Code Behind

```
  var regionItems = regionFolder.Children;
            if (regionItems.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Node region in regionItems) {
                    if (region.GetProperty(FieldName.REGIONNAME) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(region.GetProperty(FieldName.REGIONNAME).Value)) {
                        ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(region.GetProperty(FieldName.REGIONNAME).Value, region.Id.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            //ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, "Choose");
            ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose", "0"));
```

here REGIONNAME= our field name,